# ngClass string binding expression with class map

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

Is it possible to use ngClass with an expression AND a class map? I want to conditionally add a class based on the existence of a variable as well as use that variable in the expression that creates the class.

For instance, if isActive() is true and getStatus() returns "valid" I want the class list to be "element element--active element--valid". If getStatus() returns undefined I want the class list to be "element element--active".

```
<div
  class="element"
  ng-class="{
   'element--active': ctrl.isActive(),
   'element--{{ ctrl.getStatus() }}': ctrl.getStatus() 
  }"></div>
```

Doesn't seem to work.

```
<div 
  class="element element--{{ctrl.getStatus()}}"
  ng-class="{
   'element--active': ctrl.isActive()
  }"></div>
```

Works but then there's an extra hanging "element--" if getStatus() returns undefined.

Do I have to add a method in my controller to handle the class generation?

Comment: It looks like this would benefit from a directive that took the status and added all the required classes. You could do all the string building in there and hide it all from the template and controller

Answer (score 2):

i'd suggest to make just one function call to get the classes. It will make it cleaner and have the class logic in one place.

In your controller:

```
this.getElementStatus = function(){
   var rules = {active:this.isActive()}; //Prefix with element-- {element--active:}
   rules[this.getStatus()] = true; //Prefix with element--, rules['element--' + this.getStatus()] = true
   return rules;
}
```

and your view would just be:

```
<div 
  class="element"
  ng-class="ctrl.getElementStatus()"></div>
```

It seems like your `element--` is redundant with the rule instead make use of cascadeability(CSS) property. and define rules as :

Example:

```
.element.active{ /*....*/ }
.element.success {/*...*/}
.element.error{/*...*/}
```

This will help in maintenance, gets more verbose and get to the natural way of adding css rules and could remove these kind of complexities from the view.

You could as well do:

```
<div class="element" 
     ng-class="{'active': ctrl.isActive(), '{{ctrl.getStatus()}}':true}"
```

or :

```
<div class="element" 
     ng-class="[ctrl.isActive() ? 'active' : '', ctrl.getStatus()]"
```

If you don't mind getting a `true` added as a rule(should not affect anything anyways) then,

```
 <div class="element" 
     ng-class="[!ctrl.isActive() || 'element--active' , 'element--' + ctrl.getStatus()]">
```

Comment: I'm using BEM (http://csswizardry.com/2013/01/mindbemding-getting-your-head-round-bem-syntax/) for my CSS so that's why it might seem redundant.

Comment: @ShyGuy ah ok it is a generator.. Hate that way it generates.. :) see my updates with array syntax as well. Cant you just combine them to one function on the controller and call it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use class and ng-class map on the same element. But since your class name is dynamic you will have to something like this.

```
<div
  ng-class="'element '
            + (ctrl.isActive() ? ' element--active' : '') 
            + (ctrl.getStatus() ? ' element--' + ctrl.getStatus() : '')"></div>
```